# Custom formset templates in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, inline-formset

I am using a Django [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/formsets/) for this model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    book_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True,unique=True)
    book_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    publisher_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    author=models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

The formset is defined thus:

```
BookFormset = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book, 
    fields=('book_id','book_name', 'publisher_name'), extra=1, 
    can_delete=False)
```

The template is:

```
{{ formset.non_form_errors.as_ul }}
<table id="formset" class="form">
{% for form in formset.forms %}
  {% if forloop.first %}
  <thead><tr>
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}
    {% endfor %}
  </tr></thead>
  {% endif %}
  <tr class="{% cycle row1,row2 %}">
  {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <td>
    {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
    {% if forloop.first %}
      {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
      {{ hidden }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
      {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
      {{ field }}
    </td>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}    
</table>
```

The fields are displayed column-wise, but I would like them to be displayed row-wise.

The above code produces output like this:

```
Book name   Publisher name

book_field       Publisher_field
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
Book name   book_field

Publisher name   Publisher_field
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template, you have two `<tr>` elements, each of which contains a loop over `form.visible_fields`, each iteration of which generates a single `<th>` or `<td>`.

Change this round so that you have a single loop over `form.visible_fields`, each iteration of which contains a single `<tr>` element containing a `<th>` and a `<td>`. Like this:

```html
<table id="formset" class="form">
{% for form in formset.forms %}
  {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
  <tr class="{% cycle row1,row2 %}">
    <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
    <td>
    {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
    {% if forloop.first %}
      {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
      {{ hidden }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
      {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
      {{ field }}
    </td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}    
</table>
```

Comment: Ya you are right,field name is in bold style,how to change to normal one

Comment: Put a rule in the style sheet (`font-weight:normal`). Or use `td` instead of `th`.

Answer (score 2):

The examples above seem to show a column-wise layout, which appears to be the default layout when a formset renders itself.

To make it row-wise, use something like this:

```
<table>
    {% for form in formset.forms %}
        {% if forloop.first %}
            <thead>
                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    <th>{{ field.label }}</th>
                {% endfor %}    
            </thead>
            <tbody>
        {% endif %}

        <tr class="{% cycle row1,row2 %}">                        
            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                <td>
                    {% if forloop.first %}
                        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                            {{ hidden }}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}

                    {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                    {{ field }}
                </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% if forloop.last %}
            </tbody>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}    
</table>
```